# How to mesh a French biscuit (modulated ellipsoid)

Tags: mesh

I would like to create a boundary mesh of the following ellipsoid, whose thickness is modulated along its long axis:

[image]

The surface parametrization I used for it is:

```
{a, b, c} = {2, 5, 10};
s[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := {a (1.2 - Sin[\[Theta]]), b (1.2 - Sin[\[Theta]]), c}*{Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]};
ParametricPlot3D[
 s[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

A simple meshing attempt is:

```
dr = DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion[s[\[Theta], \[Phi]], {{\[Theta], 0 \[Pi], \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}}]]
ToBoundaryMesh[dr]["Wireframe"]
```

However, that leads to a triangulation problem at either pole ($\theta = 0 \lor \theta=\pi$):

[image]

Taking a step back and trying to mesh a simple ellipsoid seems to work well using the in-built `Ellipsoid` and `ImplicitRegion` functions:

```
ToBoundaryMesh[
  DiscretizeGraphics[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}],
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] =
  ImplicitRegion[(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 + (z/c)^2 == 1, {x, y, z}];
ToBoundaryMesh[
  DiscretizeRegion[\[ScriptCapitalR], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1,
   Axes -> True]]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

But it also fails for the ParametricPlot3D version:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[
 ParametricPlot3D[{a, b, c}*{Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]],
    Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta],
   0.0 \[Pi], \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
```

[image]

---

How can I get rid of the meshing problem at the poles?

Comment: What is a "French biscuit"? A [ladyfinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladyfinger_(biscuit))?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for extending my english candy vocabulary ;)

Comment: Then you may like [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cookies).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Manually derived implicit region:

```
Block[{a, b, c},
 {a, b, c} = {2, 5, 10};
 DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[(25 c^2 (b^2 x^2 + a^2 y^2))/(
    a^2 b^2 (c^2 - z^2) (6 - 5 Sqrt[1 - z^2/c^2])^2) == 
    1, {{x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, {z, -c, c}}],
  MaxCellMeasure -> "Length" -> 0.1]
 ]
```

[image]

---

*Addendum: Alternative method.*

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> "Length" -> 0.05];
Block[{a, b, c},
 {a, b, c} = {2, 5, 10};
 MeshRegion[
  s[##2] & @@@ 
   CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", 
    MeshCoordinates@reg.RotationMatrix[1.^-8, {1., 1., 1.}]], 
  MeshCells[reg, 2]]
 ]
```

The cells of the mesh get deformed by the transformation `s[]`, so it is probably not as good as the above.  On the other hand, you don't need to eliminate the parameters from the parametrization `s[]`, which might be difficult in other cases.

Comment: Solve the `x` and `y` coordinates for sine and cosine of phi. The the sum of the squares is `1`, and this eliminates phi.  Then solve the `z` coordinate for cosine of theta and eliminate theta.

Comment: Can one say that in general, it is better to use `ImplicitRegion` than polar 2d parametrizations? Is there a (simple) way to transform the crappy mesh (singularity at pole) from the polar parametrization into a nice mesh?

Comment: @Oscillon (1) I would think so, because a (triangulated) rectangular grid is mapped onto the closed surface. (2)  Not that I know of.

Comment: @Oscillon I added a parametric alternative that has a couple of restrictions.  The surface must be parametrized over a sphere.  And the cells cannot be refined where needed to make a smooth surface; one might be able to use the `MeshRefinementFunction` option to refine the sphere where needed (maybe in `ToElementMesh[]` since I can't get it to work in `DiscretizeRegion`).